# Helm sub-chart used by multiple instances of the parent

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have followed the [Helm Subchart documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) to create a parent chart with a sub-chart.
When I install the parent chart, the sub-chart comes along for the ride. Great!
However, if I try to install another instance of the parent chart with a different name, I get an error saying the sub-chart already exists.

> Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: existing resource conflict: kind: Service, namespace: my-namespace, name: my-subcharts-service

I had expected the sub-chart to be installed if it did not already exist. And if it did exist I expected everything to be ok.  Eg I thought it  would work like a package management system eg pip/yum/npm

*Is there a way to share a sub chart (or other helm construct) between multiple instances of a parent chart?*

Comment: `$ helm version` 
`version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.2", GitCommit:"19e47ee3283ae98139d98460de796c1be1e3975f", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.5"}`

Comment: Same error on `version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.1.0", GitCommit:"b29d20baf09943e134c2fa5e1e1cab3bf93315fa", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.8"}`

Comment: Short answer:
No

Long Answer:
That depends on the kind of resources. It is somewhat common practice in helm chart development to let the user the choice of either referencing existing resources or let the helm chart create the resource if its already present. That's whats usually done with serviceAccounts in helm charts. But i'm afraid there's no generic mechanism to handle that for you.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [helmsman](https://github.com/Praqma/helmsman). Maybe this will work for you.